# HTML5/CSS3 + BxSlider - Media Query for small or larger images at different resolutions

Tags: jquery, html, css, media-queries, bxslider

Building a responsive site. Basically, I want to have two sets of images for my BxSlider - one set for display up to a certain window size, the other set for anything above that size. I have tried approaches along these lines but BxSlider doesnt transition smoothly between states (nor did I really expect it to):

```
    <ul class="bxslider">

        <li class="display_below_size"><img src="/img/image1.jpg" /></li>

        <li class"display_above_size"><img src="/img/image2.jpg" /></li>

    </ul>
```

```
.display_below_size {
    display:block;
}


.display_above_size {
    display:none;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1300px) {

.display_below_size {
    display:none;
}


.display_above_size {
    display:block;
}

}
```

Do you think I should write some javascript to sort this out or is there a way to do it with css?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So you want to transition from one to the other on window resize?

Comment: Thanks for replying. Yes, thats right. I have also begun trying to do this with jQuery - as I assume that there is no easy way to do it with just html/css. Any suggestions for good approaches to this problem are much appreciated!

Comment: You are correct in saying there is no way to do it in pure CSS. with jQuery you would need to fade out/fade in the two parts on `$(window).resize(function() {...` But for what functionality? Users won't be resizing their windows much, and when they do they expect it to be jumpy. It just adds more bulk to your website that you don't really need, especially if you aren't using jQuery anywhere else

Comment: Thanks for the advice. jQuery is used elsewhere on the site for the slider, which is also used on other pages. The functionality of a script that smooths the transition is limited, I grant you, but I suppose I just wanted the transitions to be smooth if someone does resize their browser, or rotates their phone. The two image sets would vary in their ratios, so that one set would be more suited for  larger, wider screens and the other would be better for phones etc.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this @Sirrah ?  I'm pondering the same issue